# Number of terms in $(a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_k)^n$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Number of terms in $(a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_k)^n$ is 
$${n+k-1 \choose k-1}$$
I know that this is stars and bars but How does this theorem applies here ?
Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about how to multiply out the terms. If $n=2$ (i.e., we're multiplying two groups of terms), $(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k)(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k) = a_1a_1 + a_1a_2 + \dots + a_1a_k + a_2a_1 + \dots + a_ka_k$. Each term come from picking one term from the first group, one from the second, and multiplying them together. If $n=3$, the terms look like $a_1a_1a_1$, $a_1a_1a_2$, etc..

In general, each term is generated by picking one term from each of the $n$ groups, so it looks like $a_1a_1a_2a_3a_3a_3a_5$ with $n$ terms total. Combining terms with the same base, this becomes$a_1^{i_1}a_2^{i_2}\cdots a_k^{i_k}$. Since each term $a_j$ is repeated $i_j$ times in the original format, and the original format had a total of $n$ terms, we have $i_1 + i_2 + \dots + i_k = n$. We have $n$ units to divide between the $k$ exponents. This should look more like classic stars and bars now: imagine we choose the $k$ exponents in the following manner. We have $n$ stars and $k-1$ bars to arrange in a line. After arranging them, we let $i_1$ be the number of stars before the first bar, $i_2$ be the number of stars between the first bar and the second bar, etc. The number of ways to arrange the stars and bars is exactly the same as the number of ways to choose the exponents.

Comment: Thanks again but I can't understand the first and second line.

Comment: What do you mean by picking up $a_j$ in $n$ sums?

Comment: @Abbas I've added an example; is it helpful?

Comment: I just cant understand the first thing you have metioned. ''we know that each term is in the form of....''

Comment: @Abbas It's a generalization of the FOIL rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOIL_method) for sums with more than two terms. Are you familiar with the FOIL rule?

Comment: @Abbas Actually the quote "We know that each term is in the form of..." is from gimusi's answer, not mine. Did you mean to comment on gimusi's answer?

Comment: Yes it gone wrong.

Comment: But you have said that

Comment: I'm familiar with FOIL Of course.

Comment: @Abbas sorry, that was when I thought you were talking about my first line. Do you understand my answer now?

Comment: No problem! A question,are you just talking about one term multiplied another paranthesis or  the so called FOIL operation on ALL  terms from $a_1$ all the way up to $a_k$ ?

Comment: @Abbas You can generalize to apply to all.

Answer (score 0):

We know that each term is in the form $$a_1^{i_1}a_2^{i_2}\cdots a_k^{i_k}$$ with $$i_1 + i_2 + \dots + i_k = n$$

thus the problem reduce to find the number of partition of n as sum of $k$ integers $\ge$ 1.

The trick to solve the problem is to consider $n+k-1$ boxes which you can fill with $k-1$ balls, with no more than one balls for each box, in this way the remaining empty boxes correspond to the partition thus we have

$${n+k-1 \choose k-1}$$